# Django - How use generic views from a Django external App in my own App?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new to Django...

I have installed a Django external App called Haystack, this external App have a "views.py" file inside "python2.6/site-packages/haystack". I think this "views.py" is called a "generic view" in Django terms.

This generic view is called using "urls.py" like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views', 
                   url(r'^search/$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'), 
)
```

I need to make the jump from this generic views to my App. My question goes in the direction of How Can I Do This?

The code of Haystack "views.py" goes like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm, FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.query import EmptySearchQuerySet


RESULTS_PER_PAGE = getattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE', 20)


class SearchView(object):
    ...

    def __init__(self, template=None, load_all=True, form_class=None, searchqueryset=None, context_class=RequestContext, results_per_page=None):
    ...

    def __call__(self, request):
    ...

    def build_form(self, form_kwargs=None):
    ...

    def get_query(self):
    ...

    def get_results(self):
    ...

    def build_page(self):
    ...

    def extra_context(self):
    ...

    def create_response(self):
    ...


def search_view_factory(view_class=SearchView, *args, **kwargs):
    ...


class FacetedSearchView(SearchView):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    def build_form(self, form_kwargs=None):
    ...

    def extra_context(self):
    ...


def basic_search(request, template='search/search.html', load_all=True, form_class=ModelSearchForm, searchqueryset=None, context_class=RequestContext, extra_context=None, results_per_page=None):
    ...
```

Can someone give what steps I should follow to take out the code from the "urls.py" and put the thing working in my "views.py" App?

Best Regards,

Comment: Just a note, "views.py" is not called a generic view. views.py is just a container for views (generic or normal). Usually [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views/) mean simple views that do one task and can be used in many situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),`. You also might want to read "[Getting started with Haystack](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html)"

Try:

```
#your root urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import FacetedSearchView

sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(author='john')

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
url(r'^/my_custom_very_special_url$', FacetedSearchView(
    template='my/special/path/to/faceted_search.html',
    searchqueryset=sqs,
    form_class=FacetedSearchForm
), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

BTW, it's [all in the docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html#views).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I need to use other template that the one that is defined in Haystack "views.py". There is some way to pass the variables to the template from my App "views.py"?

Comment: @Andre, you need only template and nothing else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivan, I need to Faceted search to my template and call other name than "search/" in the URI.

Comment: Thank for the reply. The code works. The only problem is when I use " 'haystack.views', " in the urlpatterns, combined with other URIs from my App, It brokes, I can't access any of URIs. If I use only " 'haystack.views', url(r'^resultados/$', FacetedSearchView(template='myapp_tmp/pgresults.html', searchqueryset=sqs, form_class=FacetedSearchForm), name='haystack_search'), " it works well. Any clue about what is happen here, I see that the problem is the " 'haystack.views', " in the urlpatterns. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It is working now. I must to put that two patterns in the beginning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow all the steps in the [docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html)?

Use the [extra_context](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html#extra-context-self) method to add or overwrite the other variables in the context.